# Bash how to pass parameters in crontab case

Tags: linux, bash, cron, case

Hello i'm trying to pass parameters in my crontab but i can't understand why it doesn't work.

This is my script:

```html
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1" >> /home/ferdinando/script/logfile.txt 
# Everything below will go to the file 'log.out':

case "$1" in 
start)
   echo "$1"
   exec ./run.sh 
   ;;
stop)
   echo "$1"
   exec ./stop.sh
   ;;
status)
   ;;
*)
   echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
esac

exit 0
```

crontab:

```html
* * * * * /home/ferdinando/script/script.sh $1 >> /home/ferdinando/script/logfile.txt
```

Basically I can't pass the start parameter in such a way as to run the script run.sh, I made several tests using in the crontab "start" instead of "$ 1" but without success.

Comment: Instead of `$1` in your crontab, write the string you want to pass to your script (start, stop, or status).

Comment: `./run.sh` only works if the current directory (`$PWD`) is the directory that contains `run.sh`, when the `script.sh` program is run.  One way to fix it is to use an absolute path (e.g. `/home/ferdinando/script/run.sh`).  Another option is to `cd` to the correct directory before running `./run.sh`.  You could do that either in `script.sh` or on the `crontab` line.

Comment: @user1934428 yeah i add $1, but if i add $1 or start for example nohing change now i'm changing the script to see if it works.

Comment: Post your modified script (in particular the part where you use the parameter), and also post your modified crontab entry.

Comment: @user1934428Now it works!

#!/bin/bash
start() {
    exec /home/ferdinando/script/run.sh
}

stop() { 
    exec /home/ferdinando/script/stop.sh
#eventualmente qua ci va pkill -f nome del processo
}


case "$1" in 
start) start;;
stop) stop;;
restart) stop, start;;
*)
   echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}" >&2
   exit 1
   ;;

esac

Crontab: 
* * * * * /home/ferdinando/script/script.sh >> /home/ferdinando/script/logfile.txt

// I don't know how to go a head.